# Every Hausdorff space is a Fréchet space?

Tags: general-topology

1. Every Hausdorff space is a Fréchet space?
2. Not every Fréchet space is a Hausdorff space?

Can you help me, please? Thanks to all.

Comment: Aren't Frechet spaces vector spaces as well?

Comment: There are at least three different things called Fréchet spaces: (1) topological spaces in which sequential closure is the same as closure; (2) $T_1$ spaces; and (3) a special kind of topological vector space. I suspect that you mean (2), but you need to clarify which is meant.

Comment: Sorry. I mean $T_1$ spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space. Observe the definitions of the $T_1$ and $T_2$ axioms:

$T_1$ axiom: Given distinct $a, b \in X$, there is a neighborhood $A$ of $a$ and $B$ of $b$ such that $a \notin B$ and $b \notin A$.

$T_2$ axiom: Given distinct $a, b \in X$, there is a neighborhood $A$ of $a$ $B$ of $b$ such that $A \cap B=\emptyset$.

Frechet spaces (as clarified) follow the $T_1$ axiom. Hausdorff spaces follow the $T_2$ axiom. There is a pronounced difference in the strength of these two axioms (one statement in fact implies the other). Statements 1. and 2. follow simply from applying these definitions.

Comment: Statement 2 requires, besides applying definitions, an example of a $T_1$ space which is not a $T_2$ space.

Comment: True. But the definition guides you towards an example.